# android onResume not restoring image values

Tags: android, bitmap, recycle

I use `AnimationDrawable` animation, and after animation is finished or activity is closed im recycling bitmaps. So i start activity for first time and animation is happening, but if i close activity and open it again, im getting error `trying to use a recycled bitmap`.

Why `onResume` code isnt recreating image values ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    animationImage = (ImageView) animation_dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivAnimation);
    animationImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
    animationImage.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            animation = (AnimationDrawable) animationImage.getBackground();
            animation.start();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    animation.stop();
    animation_dialog.dismiss();

    for (int i = 0; i < animation.getNumberOfFrames(); ++i) {

        Drawable frame = animation.getFrame(i);
        if (frame instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            ((BitmapDrawable) frame).getBitmap().recycle();
        }
        frame.setCallback(null);
    }
    animation.setCallback(null);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    animationImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
    animation = (AnimationDrawable) animationImage.getBackground();
}
```

Comment: start your animation in onResume, not onCreate.

Comment: posting a runnable in onCreate is not needed here.  you are already in the foreground thread so touching the UI elements is ok.

Comment: runnable is making my animation run on all devices, if not using runnable animation isnt playing on some devices...

Comment: and afterall its not about runnable or oncreate methods, its about why `onResume` isnt restoring image values